# How do I change chmod settings to allow for file upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, nearlyfreespeech

I've been trying to get get my PHP script to upload files. However, I come across this error:

```
  Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/faceBackground.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /f5/mvcsf/public/portfolios/members_profile_chg.php on line 31

  Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/f5/mvcsf/tmp/phpjY9EBB' to 'images/faceBackground.png' in /f5/mvcsf/public/portfolios/members_profile_chg.php on line 31
```

After scouring multiple solutions on Stackoverflow, I got the hint that I should change the chmod settings. So I went into Filezilla and tried to change the file permissions for `members_profile_chg.php`(which contains the upload script) to `0755` and then to `0644`, but neither worked. Any ideas? I'm using nearlyfreespeech as my web server if that makes any difference.

Comment: Maybe you created the folder `images` using like a FTP account which may create it for your user, and the PHP script runs on a different user that has no write access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chmod 0777 the `images` folder instead of files.

Comment: you will have to give full permission `0777` due to strictness of some servers.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick! will accept your answer once it hits the time limit...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `images` directory is accessible and writeable (rwx) for the server user (probably `apache`).

```
~$ chmod g+rwx,o+rwx images/
```

Note that this makes the directory world-writable. Better is to only give the server user access (assuming it is apache):

```
~$ chown apache images/
~$ chmod g+rwx,o+rx images/
```

More information can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

The numerical values you want to try are `0775` or `0777`.

Answer (score 0):

give permission to target folder folder in which  permission 0755 or 0777 will work .also make sure that there is  a folder named 'images' in the 'portfolios'

if the images is on the root try

move_uploaded_file("/images/faceBackground.png")